# HTML_QuickForm addGroupRule, 'compare'

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this!

I'm having trouble adding a compare group rule type with HTML_QuickForm.

Here is the code:

```
$form->addGroupRule( 'phone', array( 
    'phone1' => array(
        array( 'Enter Num', 'required' ),
        array( '6 numbers', 'rangelength', array( 6, 6 ) )
    ),
    'phone2' => array( 
        array( 'Enter Num', 'required' )
    ),
    array( 'phone1', 'phone2' ) => array(
        array( 'Must be equal', 'compare' ) 
    )
));
```

The last part is the one causing the problem.  The form will validate even if the two fields are different.

```
array( 'phone1', 'phone2' ) => array(
        array( 'Must be equal', 'compare' ) 
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't have an array as a key.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer.  What do you use instead of the array to have phone1 compare '==' with phone2?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform2.rules.list.php).

Comment: This [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform.html-quickform.addgrouprule.php)       is more relevant but doesn't instruct how to add a compare type rule for a group.  The problem is that I can't compare two fields in a group to be equal........any help with that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Understood, but you can pass the compare rule from phone1 to phone2.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a validation to phone1 compared to phone2. So it would be something like this,

```
'phone1' => array(
    array( 'Must be equal', 'compare',
            array('operator' => '==', 'operand' => 'phone2') ) 
)
```

Give it a try.